# Wont delete game object repeatedly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two issues, when I delete Game Objects with the box tag, it doesn't delete multiple even when I write the line multiple times.

I also found out that when I copy the box prefab with Instantiate, the box collider is disabled even though the prefab has it enabled.

I am fairly new to C# and I don't feel like my code is optimized well, so if anyone could also help with that, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RestartLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentLevel = 1f;
    public GameObject boxPrefab;
    public GameObject firstBox;
    Vector3 a = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Reset"))
        {
            if (currentLevel == 1f)
            {
                Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));
                Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));
                Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));

                GameObject newBox = Instantiate(boxPrefab);
                newBox.transform.position = a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is almost fine. But `Destroy()` will destroy at the end of the frame.
So your code ...

```
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("box"));
```

... will find the SAME object 3 times in the frame. Therefore only one is deleted.

How to solve? Use [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) or delete across multiple frames.

```
GameObject[] destroyObject;
destroyObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(destroyTag);
foreach (GameObject oneObject in destroyObject)
    Destroy (oneObject);
```